# decrypt in .js archive

Tags: javascript

I can not decrypt and not even know what type of encryption uses this code. thank you

```
 eval(function (a, b, c, d, e, f) {
        e = function (a) {
            return a.toString(b);
        };
        if (!'' ['|'](/^/, String)) {
            while (c--) f[e(c)] = d[c] || e(c);
            d = [function (a) {
                return f[a];
            }];
            e = function () {
                return 'ifr2|document|ready|function|if|liberado|false|ifr|attr|id|appendTo|publicidade|propaganda2';
            };
            c = 1;
        }
        while (c--) if (d[c]) a = a['|'](new RegExp('replace' + e(c) + 'replace', '\\w+'), d[c]);
        return a;
    }('0', 13, 13, '#b-c' ['split']('#0'), 0, {}));
```

Answer (score 0):

*There is nothing to 'decrypt' as there is nothing encrypted* (you might however call it 'obscured').
It is just plain vanilla javascript (which, as a developer, you *should* be able to read if you have access to *all* the code).

However, there are 2 severe problems (but explaining them should lead you to an answer):

1. We do not know what method `String.prototype['|']` does, as you haven't posted it's code (and other code that this function might rely on).
   You might be able to `console.log( String.prototype['|'].toSource() );` to obtain that code.
   We know however that it expects (at least) 2 arguments (in order):

   1. regular expression object       `/replaceifr2|document|ready|function|if|liberado|false|ifr|attr|id|appendTo|publicidade|propaganda2replace/`
   2. function `d` (if the `if` condition was true)
      OR string `#b-c` (if the `if` condition has failed), in which case it would have tried to generate regex `/replace0replace/`.
2. `new RegExp(/*string here*/, '\\w+')` **will throw an error** because the second optional argument `\\w+` is an **illegal flag**.
   Regardless if the condition fails or not, the code you have currently posted *will fail*.

I have tried to deduce what the `|` on String's prototype might do (I like riddles and am sad I couldn't solve this one) but there is just not enough code in your question. I highly suspect it is part of an iframe injection (and watcher) routine.